# Using Promises to connect React Components

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux

I came up with solution to a React problem and want to see what people think.

**The Problem**: I have a really big form component with lots of subforms that can each be expanded and minimized. The parent form component is already managing a ton of state because all of the sub forms report their input values to it. There is also an "ErrorBubble" component. Whenever the form is validated and there is an error, the ErrorBubble appears and finds the first invalid field in the form and moves to it. The ErrorBubble also has to dynamically update its position as the size of the form changes, which happens if you minimize or expand any of the subforms. So, the problem is, how do you get each of the subForms to communicate to the ErrorBox that it needs to reposition?

**The traditional solution**: Just have the parent form component manage all the state. Each subform reports any change in its expanded state to the parent component, which causes a re-render of everything including the ErrorBubble.

**Cons:** Parent component already has a ton of methods and state it is managing, I don't want to add more. Forces a re-render of the whole parent form component

**The Redux Solution:** Have each subform dispatch a redux action and the ErrorBubble connected to the Redux store.

**Cons:** Lot of boilerplate to create. Have to create a reducer and a piece of redux store just for this. Have to design the redux actions. Have to connect ErrorBubble to redux. Also updating the redux store on every resize of the subforms may be inefficient?

**My Solution:** I have a DeferredTask custom object helper. I create an instance of it in the constructor of the parent form component and save it as state. Here is the custom object:

```
export class DeferredTask {
  constructor () {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.resolve = resolve
      this.reject = reject

      this.reset = function () {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          this.resolve = resolve
          this.reject = reject

        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I then passed this.state.deferredTask onto all the subforms and the ErrorBubble as a prop.

Whenever the ErrorBubble mounts, it runs a method that listens for this deferredTask to resolve, and when it unmounts it rejects the task to close it out so it doesn't remain perpetually pending:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.repositionErrorBubble()
  this.deferredTask()
}

deferredTask = () => {
  this.props.deferredTask.reset()
  this.props.deferredTask.promise
    .then(()=>{
      if(this._calledComponentWillUnmount) {
        return
      }
      this.repositionErrorBubble()
      this.deferredTask()
    })
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  this.props.deferredTask.reject()
}
```

Each of the subforms have:

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  this.props.deferredTask.resolve()
}
```

Now every time any subforms updates they resolve the promise and the ErrorBubble runs its then(). It needs to check if the ErrorBubble component is scheduled to unmount because you cant update state of an unmounting component. Otherwise, it runs the code to reposition the ErrorBubble then resets the promise and starts listening to it again.

**Pros:** Only create one piece of state and pass down one prop from parent form component. Pretty minimal code surface area connecting these components. Don't have to go through the regular prop channels to update. componentWillReceiveProps is already bloated with a ton of other checks.

Its like a quasi pub-sub pattern but neater?

What do you guys think? Is this a react anti-pattern because there is data being passed horizontally and not vertically? Keep in mind the deferredTask object is still available as state in the parent component and is being passed down... Does that make it any better?

Are there pitfalls for using asynchronous promises? Could it bite me in the butt? Since the only things triggering the resolves are successive user interactions and the promise is reset after each interaction, it shouldn't ever cause any confusion which promise is resolving should it? So far i've tried spamming the subform resize and it has not caused any problems.

Is there a better way to do this that works with React?

Comment: Hmm, definitely a react anti-pattern, but hey it works so?? I can see another way of doing this by turning `ErrorBubble` into an HOC that passes down the `repositionErrorBubble` method as prop. Then, you can wrap all of your subforms in your HOC and call `this.props.repositionErrorBubble` in `componentDidUpdate` in each one. The only thing I don't like about your solution is that it makes it a lot harder for other developers to understand the event flow of these components.

Comment: Do you mean
HOC [ subform, subform, subform] type wrap? Or
HOC[subform], HOC[subform], HOC[subform]?

Is it really harder for developers to understand the event flow? How is it harder than passing a method down from the parent component to the subforms that updates the parent component, and to pass down the updated state to the ErrorBubble? How is that more clear?

Comment: Yeah I mean HOC[subform], HOC[subform], HOC[subform]. You're resolving promises in random places, it's not easy to follow the when/where/why promises are being resolved/rejected. HOC is a react standard pattern so it's a more familiar/understandable to other react developers. I can't look at your code and understand what's going or why you are using promises without your explanations.

Comment: If you weren't around, someone could go and google react HOC and understand how it works. If you're using a custom pattern that they can't google, they will have a much harder time maintaining your code.

Comment: Well deferred objects are a pattern :) I think if you name the deferred object well it should be pretty self-explanatory? defferedErrorBubbleRefresh. Then all you have to do is search for where the defferedErrorBubbleRefresh gets resolved and where its promised and you are good to go!

Comment: Regarding the HOC method, thats interesting but how do they connect back to the original ErrorBubble. Wouldnt each HOC have its own internal state? Its not like each change in one HOC affects the state in all the others is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157104/discussion-between-leo-fabrikant-and-chase-deanda).